CORS Issue: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
I am getting a CORS error on my Angular application.
Backend: Flask
Front end: Angular
I have enabled cors on my api function.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS  # Import CORS
import app as parsing_module

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/api/parse-resume', methods=['OPTIONS'])
def options():
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'})

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')  # Or specify your domain
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')  # Include any other headers you may need
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
    return response

@app.route('/api/parse-resume', methods=['POST'])
def parse_resume():
    if 'resume' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file uploaded'}), 400

    file = request.files['resume']

    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'error': 'No selected file'}), 400

    # Here, you would call your resume parsing function
    resume_data = parsing_module.extract_resume_details(file)  # Adjust according to your function

    return jsonify(resume_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

API_CALL:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Resume } from './app.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FeaturesService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/parse-resume'; // Your API endpoint

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  parseResume(file: File): Observable<Resume> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('resume', file);

    return this.http.post<Resume>(this.apiUrl, formData); 
  }
}

Also I have used proxy configuration in my angular app in an attempt to solve this.
proxy.conf.json:
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000", 
      "secure": false
    }
}

I have not come across anyone that had this issue with angular and flask. Please let me know if you  know the fix.
What particular issue is causing this. Is this a backend issue or front end issue?

To me it seems like you're doing double duty. You're using the CORS module, but you're also manually adding the headers with the @after_request decorator. I am not 100% if that's causing the issue, but you can try disabling the CORS module and just (only) add them manually
to be exact, comment out this line:
CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})

you also won't need this if it works
from flask_cors import CORS  # Import CORS

also, maybe unrelated, but this seems a little weird to me:
@app.route('/api/parse-resume', methods=['OPTIONS'])
def options():
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok'})

OPTIONS requests are automatic preflight requests, I don't see why you're handling them with an actual route. I wouldn't rely to check if your api works based on this route, probably just remove it entirely - or maybe you meant to use a GET method instead?

Thanks for replying @c8999c-3f964f64, I am facing a different issue this time:
resume-uploader.component.ts:52
GET http://localhost:5000/api/test net::ERR_FAILED 403 (Forbidden)
testAPIFromConsole @ resume-uploader.component.ts:52
onFileSelected @ resume-uploader.component.ts:45
ResumeUploaderComponent_Template_input_change_10_listener @ resume-uploader.component.html:18
Zone - HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:change
ResumeUploaderComponent_Template @ resume-uploader.component.html:18
Zone - Promise.then
(anonymous) @ main.ts:5
Show 462 more frames

This problems seems to be unrelated to the CORS issue and you should ask it in a new question. 403 is usually an authorization issue, and not a CORS problem. If you could solve the CORS problem, you should accept the answer.

It actually didnt resolve the issue after commenting CORS(app, resources={r"": {"origins": ""}})
